# DB2 SQL: Union a recursive query performed on BOM file back to it's root list

Tags: sql, recursion, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

Business Case:  Using a single query (without regard to performance), provide a list of Part No.s by Plant given assumptions. (Assumptions listed as comments in the pseudo-code below.)

```
**Query 1** -- Parts sold in last 3 years
Plant, PartNo
UNION
**Query 2** -- Parts created in ERP in last year
Plant, PartNo
UNION
**Query 3** -- Parts in Inventory at run time
Plant, PartNo
UNION
**Query 4** -- Parts received in last 3 years
Plant, PartNo
UNION
**Query 5** -- Component parts of parts from queries 1 thru 4.
```

The source table for Query 5 looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE BOMTABLE (
    PLANT AS PLANT
    PARENT AS PARENT
    CHILD AS CHILD
    QTYPER AS QTYPER
    ...
);
```

I'm able to handle queries 1 thru 4 and UNION them together to output PLANT, PARTNO, but the fifth query has got me stuck. I believe I need to make use of DB2's CONNECT_BY_ROOT function along with START WITH and CONNECT BY PRIOR for something like the pseudo-code below and UNION it to Queries 1-4.

```
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT
    PLANT,
    CHILD AS PARTNO
FROM BOMTABLE
START WITH
    PLANT IN (Queries 1 thru 4)
    AND
    PARENT IN (Queries 1 thru 4)
CONNECT BY PRIOR
    PLANT IN (Queries 1 thru 4)
    AND
    CHILD = PARENT
```

However I'm confused when it comes to the START WITH and CONNECT BY PRIOR statements.

1. Would I have to use Queries 1-4 as a source for the START WITH clause? How would I do this given that
   I have to be sure when executing that the PARENT honors the appropriate PLANT.
2. Would I carry the same condition from START WITH over to CONNECT BY PRIOR for PLANT? and for PARTNO I
   set up my recursion where CHILD = PARENT?

Using this documentation for reference:

[IBM - Using recursive queries](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/sqlp/rbafyrecursivequeries.htm)

Comment: Use cte (common table expression) to get resultset from union of query 1 to 4 and use CTE in final select

Comment: isn't this terribly complicated?  How many programmers would be able to understand the code?  To get a list of all nested component items of BOM I would abstract the logic into a table function. Or easier, an SQL procedure that writes the component items to a temporary table.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Recursive Common Table Expression (RCTE) rather than the non standard `CONNECT BY` construct

There is an BOM example here  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzrecurse.htm